# What is the Specific Type of Word that Includes Stellar, Sylvan, etc

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

I have recently become fixated on the idea of words which are defined as "of, or relating to, [noun]"- stellar means "of stars", sylvan means "of trees". These are the only two samples that I have been able to find in the wild. Futility Closet fairly recently ran a post that listed roughly 20 of them, and identified them as 'modifiers' [1], but searching for modifiers on google only results in words like nearly or barely, which don't really fit my target.

Is there a name for these words or some way I could find samples in a dictionary?

[1]http://www.futilitycloset.com/2013/08/22/in-a-word-433/

Comment: These are two Latin adjective-forming suffixes, -an and -al/-ar, applied to two different Latin roots, one for forest and one for star. Get a Latin-English dictionary, look up the Latin root for the noun you want in the English side, then look for Latin adjectives formed from it in the Latin side of the dictionary. A substantial portion of them will have one of these suffixes. Like  [these English words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Latin_dissimilation.pdf).

Comment: I tried this with dreams and wound up finding a few places where 'Somniatal' is used, but that is mostly relegated to the names of species in Science Fiction. Instead, the word Oneiric is used to mean 'Of Dreams' and it comes from Greek rather than Latin.

Comment: 'Stellar' is defined as 'of or relating to a star or stars'; 'canine' is variously defined as 'of or resembling a dog; doglike' (Collins) /  'of, relating to, or characteristic of the canids' [AHD]. One sense of 'sylvan' might be defined as 'inhabiting woodland'. Whether or not an adjective is defined using a plural noun, a singular noun or a non-count noun doesn't seem to be all that significant. It's determined by first appropriateness, then choice.

Comment: Not to discredit your point, of course, and your method (based on the Futility Closet link) seems to work in a fourth to a third of cases.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, you're right, I'll edit the question. I suppose what I'm actually looking for is adjectives that relate nouns to other nouns, in a sense.

Comment: They're all just adjectives that happen to be refer to categories of objects. Is there a specific word for this? Probably not. Maybe I can coin one: _cladic adjectives_

Answer (score 1):

The process you seem to be concerned with is [*derivation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(linguistics)):

> the process of forming a new word on the basis of an existing word, e.g. *happiness* and *unhappy* from *happy*, or *determination* from *determine*. It often involves the addition of a morpheme in the form of an affix, such as -*ness*, *un*- and -*ation* in the preceding examples.

As John Lawler explains, *sylvan* and *stellar* are derived from the Latin roots *stella* and *sylva* through addition of the Latin affixes *-ar* and *-an*. Some English affixes used to derive adjectives from English roots (and sometimes roots from other tongues) are -*y*, -*ish*, -*like*. For more examples you may Google "derived adjectives"  or --as you have now pointed out to me-- "deonominal adjectives" ('un-nouned').

Comment: This wasn't necessarily the answer I was looking for, but the third google result for that search did actually give the answer. Denominal Adjectives seem to be what I was looking for. What is the etiquette here? Do you edit your answer, or do I supply my own answer?

Comment: @Draco6slayer - Thanks, it's a term I hadn't known. I'll add it, with credit to you.

Comment: That term was un-nouned to me as well!